# XSL-FO Transformation error for instream-foreign-object

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I am transforming an XML to pdf using apache fop.

The template with fo:instream-foreign-object is throwing me an error.

**XSL**

```
<xsl:template match="disp-formula">
        <fo:instream-foreign-object width="50%" content-width="scale-to-fit">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1037" height="439"
                viewBox="0 0 1037 439">
                <image height="439px" width="1037px"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
                        <xsl:text>mathml/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:text>.mml</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>                    
                </image>
            </svg>
        </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</xsl:template>
```

**Error**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.batik.dom.GenericElement
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SVGOMElement  at
>   org.apache.fop.fo.extensions.svg.SVGElement.getDimension(SVGElement.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.fo.flow.InstreamForeignObject.prepareIntrinsicSize(InstreamForeignObject.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.fo.flow.InstreamForeignObject.getIntrinsicWidth(InstreamForeignObject.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.getInlineArea(AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(AbstractGraphicsLayoutManager.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.LineLayoutManager.collectInlineKnuthElements(LineLayoutManager.java:700)
>     at
>   org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.inline.LineLayoutManager.getNextKnuthElements(LineLayoutManager.java:629)

**EDIT**

Libraries used:

```
avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar
avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar
batik-all-1.8.jar
commons-io-1.3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
fontbox-1.8.5.jar
jeuclid-core-3.1.9.jar
jeuclid-fop-3.1.9.jar
serializer-2.7.0.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar
xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
fop-2.1.jar
```

Comment: Do you get that error with any kind of image the SVG tries to link to? Or only if it is a MathML document? Can you give exact details about the Apache FOP version being used?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I hard-coded some svg image in my template, it produced the same error. And for the libraries, I will edit in the question.

Comment: @NewBeeDeveloper Why not upgrade to fop-2.3 (with all its dependencies like batik-all-1.10.jar)

Comment: @Würgspaß, I tried upgrading but the result is same.